# Searching a table based on an incoming string with Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

Assume we are working with Ruby on Rails.  We have two tables:

Attributes:

```
NAME       VALUE      CODE
Size       1          a
Size       2          b
Size       3          c
Type       Tall       a
Type       Medium     b
Type       Small      c
Material   Plastic    1
Material   Metal      2
Material   Liquid     3
Option 1   Yes        y
Option 1   No         n
Option 2   Yes        y
Option 2   No         n
```

Parts:

```
PART     SIZE     TYPE     MATERIAL    OPTION 1     OPTION 2
A1234    1        Tall     
A1233    2        Tall
A1232    3        Tall
A1231    4        Tall
.... [there may be many parts that exhibit various attributes]
A8787                      Plastic
A8786-01                   Metal       Yes
A8786-02                   Metal       No
A8785                      Liquid
A6543                                                Yes
```

I would like to take a string such as `aa2yn` and based on the position of each character, create a hash of the NAME and VALUE that lines up with that particular CODE.  So for `aa2yn`, my hash would be 
`["Size" => 1, "Type" => "Tall", "Material" => "Metal", "Option 1" => "Yes", "Option 2" => "No"]

Then I would like to query Table 2 using the data in the hash.  For each attribute, only PARTS that contain either that value, or are blank, would be returned.  So for the example string given above, the query would return:
`"A1234", "A8786-01"`.  This result can be returned in an array.  Depending on the input string, more or less parts would be returned.  (The actual version of this will be using much larger and more extensive tables, but I have scaled down for examples sake). You may assume that the order of the string is predefined and will always come in the order of the NAMES.

What would the method or methods look like to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like that:

```
select p.part 
from parts p
  left join attributes a1 on a1.name = 'Size' and p.size = a1.value 
  left join attributes a2 on a2.name = 'Type' and p.type = a2.value 
  left join attributes a3 on a3.name = 'Material' and p.material = a3.value 
  ...
where
      (a1.code is null or substring('aa2yn',1,1)=a1.code)
  and (a2.code is null or substring('aa2yn',2,1)=a2.code)
  and (a3.code is null or substring('aa2yn',3,1)=a3.code)
  ...
```

As you can see query must be hard-coded to field names and attribute names. Or the query must be generated after getting distinct names of attributes (problem is right order of attribute names).
*`substring('aa2yn',1,1)` used for explanation purpose - what parameters will be used.*

---

To use such hashes you can add after insert/update triggers to `parts` table and calculate those hashes into a separate field, replacing empty attribute values to `_` character and the this query (of course it can be done on client instead of triggers):

```
select part
from parts
where 'aa2yn' like hash
```

Still after that on large table this will work pretty slow, as no index will be used...

Comment: I'm certainly not set on using a hash if there's a better way, I just thought I might split the string into an array, and then use that to construct a hash that could be used for the query.  However, that was just my initial thought,  anything that will get me to the answer would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Rails works best with normalized tables.  You should try to normalize to the 3rd

```
create_table :sizes do |t|
  t.string :code, nil:false  #a
  t.string :value, nil:false  #1
end

create_table :types do |t|
  t.string :code, nil:false
  t.string :value, nil:false
end
```

.........

```
create_table :material_parts do |t|
  t.string :part  #A787
  t.string :value  #Plastic

end
```

Once your tables are normalized, then the joins spring forward

Comment: I considered splitting into multiple tables, but the attributes table on my real app would end up splitting into about 100 tables, so entering new values and names would not be as simple for the user.